# Proofs about Automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I got part (a) completely. The other stuff is giving me a lot of trouble though. Can you check my work so far?

For part (b) correct me if I'm wrong but gx$g^{-1}$$\in$Aut(G) because for any x$\in$G,     gx$g^{-1}$$\in$G. Then c is a homomorphism from G to Aut(G) because gx$g^{-1}$$\in$G holds for any g,x$\in$G. Is this correct? I feel like I may need more for this one. Was this enough to prove a homomorphism or no?

For part (c) z$\in$Z(G) so zg=gz for all $g\in$G so $c_z$(x)=zx$z^{-1}$=z$z^{-1}$x=x thus z is in the kernal of c. I am pretty sure this one is correct but threw it up here just in case.

d) I'm having trouble figuring out where to start.

Comment: for b) you must try $c(g_1g_2)=c(g_1)c(g_2)$

Comment: To show this I would have to show that $c_{g_1g_2}$(x)=$c_{g_1}$(x)$c_{g_2}$(x)? for an arbitrary x$\in$G

Answer (score 0):

In part b) you have show that $c_g$ maps $G$ to itself, but you also need to prove that $c_g$ preserves the multiplication operation.  That is, $c_g(xy)=c_g(x)c_g(y)$.  You also need to show that $c(gh)=c(g)\circ c(h)$.  Remember that the operation for $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is function composition.

For part c) you also need to show that if $g$ is in the kernel, then it is also in the center.  In other words, you've shown $Z(G)\subseteq\ker$, now you need to show $\ker\subseteq Z(G)$.

In part (d), note that $c$ maps $G$ onto $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, so use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I don't understand your comment for part (d)

Comment: Sorry I meant "note that" instead of "not that".  I've fixed it.

Comment: Can you find a homomorphism whose kernel is $Z(G)$ and whose image is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$?

Comment: @amcerbu : the very same $g\mapsto c_g$ has kernel $Z(G)$